# Laravel copy and move not working with large file(10GB) with s3

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5

Small files (up to 1 GB) are successfully transferred but large files return false on the move and copy functions.

both functions should work correctly for large files as well.

My code

```
try {
       //dd($param);
       $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
       $dd = $s3->move($param['source'], $param['target']);
       dd($dd);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       return [
          "status" => 0,
             "msg" => $e->getMessage(),
         ];
   }
```

Comment: In what way does your code fail? Is the exception triggered? Are you getting any errors at all, or is the copy / move failing silently?

Comment: My code fails in case of large files, no exception trigger only returns false.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html) if you upload files larger than 5GB, you have to use a multipart upload. If you're not uploading, but handling files already in a S3 bucket, the same limit applies. More [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/copying-objects-greater-than-5-gb-with-amazon-s3-batch-operations/). This blog post also mentions a 15 minute timeout limit. How much time passes between the starting of your script and the failing?